# Spring Data REST prevent InvalidFormatException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.6 and Spring Data REST. I'm using the `PATCH` endpoint created automatically from SDR for one of my model bean.
My bean has some integer fields and I tried, on purpuse, to set a string value instead.
What I receive is an exception like this:

```
    {
  "cause": {
    "cause": null,
    "message": "Can not deserialize value of type int from String \"500s\": not a valid Integer value\n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: it.server.model.checkpoints.CheckPoint[\"passStockAlert\"])"
  },
  "message": "Could not read payload!; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not deserialize value of type int from String \"500s\": not a valid Integer value\n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: it.server.model.checkpoints.CheckPoint[\"passStockAlert\"])"
}
```

My client is an Angular and I would like the customer receive a more graceful message. My exceptions are localized through messages.properties file, but in this case I can't just show a generic message.
I should point out what field is wrong and why.

This sounds like a validation exception to me. This is my bean:

```
    @Entity
public class CheckPoint extends AbstractEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2719798641638659883L;

    @NotNull(message = "The checkpoint must have a name")
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    private LocalTime openingTime;

    private LocalTime closingTime;

    @Min(value = 0, message = "The min pass stock alert must be 0")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int passStockAlert = 0;
```

Is there a way to treat this exception like the one thrown when you try to put a value less than 0 in the field `passStockAlert`?
To be precise the exception raised in that case is something like this:

```
    {
  "errors": [
    {
      "entity": "CheckPoint",
      "property": "passStockAlert",
      "invalidValue": -1,
      "message": "The min pass stock alert must be 0"
    }
  ]
}
```

==== MORE CLARIFICATIONS =====

At the moment I'm using a customization of the layout of exceptions:

```
    /**
 * According to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6555, this
 * is the standard way to customize Spring MVC exceptions.
 * 
 * In this case we customized the exception adding localization to the message
 * and adding details about the cause of the error that can be useful for
 * developers.
 * 
 * @author Daniele Renda
 *
 */
public class CustomErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {
    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(RequestAttributes requestAttributes, boolean includeStackTrace) {
        Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, includeStackTrace);
        Throwable throwable = getError(requestAttributes);

        /**
         * Adding the cause if present
         */
        if (throwable != null && throwable.getCause() != null) {
            Throwable cause = throwable.getCause();
            Map<String, Object> causeErrorAttributes = new HashMap<>();
            causeErrorAttributes.put("exception", cause.getClass().getName());
            causeErrorAttributes.put("message", cause.getMessage());
            errorAttributes.put("cause", causeErrorAttributes);
        }

        if (throwable != null) {
            boolean customizeMessage = false;

            if (throwable instanceof InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException) {
                customizeMessage = true;
            }

            /**
             * Override the messages of these exceptions
             */
            if (customizeMessage) {
                String localizedMessage = localizedMessage(throwable, locale);
                if (localizedMessage != null)
                    errorAttributes.put("message", localizedMessage);
            }
        }
        return errorAttributes;
    }

    private String localizedMessage(Throwable throwable, Locale locale) {
        if (throwable != null)
            return messageSource.getMessage(throwable.getClass().getName(), new Object[] {}, locale);
        return null;
    }

}
```

and I'm using validation listener:

```
@Override
public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
    validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", validator);
    validatingListener.addValidator("beforeSave", validator);
}
```

At the moment I'm not using any `@RestControllerAdvice` because I don't need it. So far everything is managed very well.

Comment: How are you currently handling exceptions? Are you using ExceptionHandlers perhaps ControllerAdvice?

Comment: @SeanCarroll I edited my question

Comment: It looks like you are already doing some customization for InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException. Does that not work for this particular exception?

Comment: It's not that. I'm able to customize the message but I can't create a dynamic localized message like happens for validation for the int field with the annotation min. I would prefer be able to manage that as a ValidationError

Comment: I think I'm missing an important piece of the problem. Why cant you localize the message? Check if the throwable is InvalidFormatException if it is cast to that which allow you to get the type (in this case int) and value ("500s") then you can pass a localization key to messageSource.getMessage along with an object array that contains type and value. Your InvalidFormatException message key could then be defined something like InvalidFormatException={0} is not valid for type {1}. If you think I'm on the right track I can provide what I have in a sample app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how far off the mark I am but I thought I'd provide details anyway. Given you already have the logic to get the throwable from `DefaultErrorAttributes.getError` you can then determine if its of type InvalidFormatException and handle it appropriately. In my sample I did the following

```
@Component
public class CustomErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(RequestAttributes requestAttributes, boolean includeStackTrace) {
        Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        errorAttributes.put("timestamp", new Date());
        addStatus(errorAttributes, requestAttributes);

        Throwable throwable = getError(requestAttributes);      
        if (throwable instanceof BindingResult) {
            addErrors(errorAttributes, (BindingResult) throwable, locale);
        } else if (throwable instanceof MethodArgumentNotValidException) {
            addErrors(errorAttributes, ((MethodArgumentNotValidException) throwable).getBindingResult(), locale);
        } else if (throwable instanceof InvalidFormatException) {
            addErrors(errorAttributes, (InvalidFormatException) throwable, locale);

        }
        return errorAttributes;
    }

    private void addStatus(Map<String, Object> errorAttributes,
            RequestAttributes requestAttributes) {
        Integer status = getAttribute(requestAttributes,
                "javax.servlet.error.status_code");
        if (status == null) {
            errorAttributes.put("status", 999);
            errorAttributes.put("error", "None");
            return;
        }
        errorAttributes.put("status", status);
        try {
            errorAttributes.put("error", HttpStatus.valueOf(status).getReasonPhrase());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // Unable to obtain a reason
            errorAttributes.put("error", "Http Status " + status);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T> T getAttribute(RequestAttributes requestAttributes, String name) {
        return (T) requestAttributes.getAttribute(name, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
    }

    private void addErrors(
            Map<String, Object> errorAttributes, BindingResult bindingResult, Locale locale) {
        List<ErrorDTO> errors = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ObjectError error : bindingResult.getAllErrors()) {
            ErrorDTO e = new ErrorDTO();
            e.setCode(error.getCode());
            e.setMessage(localizedMessage(error, locale));

            if (error instanceof FieldError) {
                FieldError fieldError = (FieldError) error;
                e.setField(fieldError.getField());
                e.setRejectedValue(fieldError.getRejectedValue());
            }
            errors.add(e);
        }
        errorAttributes.put("errors", errors);
    }

    private String getInvalidFormatExceptionFieldName(InvalidFormatException ex) {

        for (JsonMappingException.Reference r : ex.getPath()) {
            return r.getFieldName();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void addErrors(
            Map<String, Object> errorAttributes, InvalidFormatException ex, Locale locale) {
        List<ErrorDTO> errors = new ArrayList<>();

        ErrorDTO e = new ErrorDTO();
        e.setCode("InvalidFormatException");
        String message = localizedMessage(
                "InvalidFormatException", 
                new Object[] {ex.getTargetType().getName(), ex.getValue()},
                locale);
        e.setMessage(message);
        e.setField(getInvalidFormatExceptionFieldName(ex));
        e.setRejectedValue(ex.getValue());
        errors.add(e);
        errorAttributes.put("errors", errors);

    }

    private String localizedMessage(ObjectError error, Locale locale) {
        return messageSource.getMessage(error, locale);
    }

    private String localizedMessage(String message, Object[] args, Locale locale) {
        return messageSource.getMessage(message, args, locale);
    }
}
```

Focusing on the InvalidFormatException exception. I cast the throwable to InvalidFormatException which then allows me to grab both the field name, type and value. I wasn't a fan of the default map provided by DefaultErrorAttributes so I created a custom ErrorDTO which looks like

```
public class ErrorDTO {

    private String code;
    private String message;
    private String field;
    private Object rejectedValue;

    public ErrorDTO() {

    }

    public ErrorDTO(String code, String message) {
        this(code, message, null, null);
    }

    public ErrorDTO(String code, String message, String field, Object rejectedValue) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
        this.field = field;
        this.rejectedValue = rejectedValue;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public Object getRejectedValue() {
        return rejectedValue;
    }

    public void setRejectedValue(Object rejectedValue) {
        this.rejectedValue = rejectedValue;
    }

}
```

To get a localized message I pass in a custom message key, "InvalidFormatException" which is in a ValidationMessages.properties file and defined as

```
InvalidFormatException={1} is not valid for type {0}
```

along with the target type and value as an object array and the locale to `messageSource.getMessage`

This will produce a JSON response of

```
{
   "timestamp":1504310911502,
   "status":999,
   "error":"None",
   "errors":[
      {
         "code":"InvalidFormatException",
         "message":"500s is not valid for type int",
         "field":"passStockAlert",
         "rejectedValue":"500s"
      }
   ]
}
```